# How to create User Interface in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I want to create User Interface in JSF.
Is there any tool apart from Dreamweaver through which I can develop GUI faster in JSF?
 I've tried jQuery with JSF but it's not working with JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/jsfdesigner_overview/ if you want a visual designer.

I would suggest plain code in eclipse/netbeans though.

Comment: My boss wants very funky design :-(

Comment: Thanx Damokles...will it provide me very interactive & funky design & more importantly faster development??? I've no idea about "primefaces"